# Cisco RAM DDR3-16GB on Dell Poweredge R620

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge

Will this particular RAM - Cisco UCS-MR-1X162RZ-A 16GB DDR3-1866-MHz RDIMM/PC3-14900 (RAM DDR3-16GB) work with Dell PowerEdge R620?

Answer (score 2):

It might physically fit into a Dell PowerEdge R620, it's not guaranteed to work properly because Cisco UCS-MR-1X162RZ-A RAM modules are specifically designed for use with Cisco UCS servers.

I'll suggest using any of the following if you can't get a Dell Certified RAM;

Crucial DDR3 ECC RDIMM, Kingston DDR3 ECC RDIMM or Samsung DDR3 ECC RDIMM.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Cisco doesn't design memory. They rebadge a standard product.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this table](https://i.dell.com/sites/content/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/dell-poweredge-r620-technical-guide.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A62%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C51%2C704%2C0%5D) and the memory's hardware specs, it should:

```
Capacity (GB)   Speed (MT/s)   Type    Ranks per DIMM   Data width   SDDC support   Voltage
16              1866           RDIMM   2                x4           All modes      1.5
```

CISCO UCS-MR-1X162RZ-A: `16GB DDR3-1866-MHz RDIMM/PC3-14900/dual rank/x4/1.5v`

Unfortunately, Dell doesn't provide the proper HCL (the memory modules part numbers verified to work by the manufacturer), so you have to resort to comparing the characteristics and testing yourself.